# How do I successfully access the IBM DB2 Add-ins for Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019, db2-luw

I'm beyond frustrated. I've downloaded and installed the latest, greatest version of IBM Add-Ins for Visual Studio (11.5), along with IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI Version 11.5.

I've shut down, restarted, and even run the utility called "Register IBM Database Add-Ins" (even though I shouldn't have to, since Visual Studio 2019 Community (16.7.2) was already installed prior to installing IBM Add-Ins for Visual Studio.

I've done all of this, and all I'm trying to do is reference the IBM.Data.DB2 namespace in my Visual Basic project.

I put in my project:

```
Imports IBM.Data.DB2
```

Then in my code I added:

```
Dim conn as IBM.Data.DB2.DB2connection
```

and I get the error message "IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection is undefined."

Is there ANYONE out there who has some experience with DB2 and Visual Studio that could assist me with how to get Visual Studio / Visual Basic to talk to my DB2 server? I know the server is working because I connect to it using ODBC with Microsoft Access.  There's all kinds of documentation that says you don't want to connect with ODBC or ADO.NET, but rather you want to use this IBM Provider.

What am I missing? How can I get Visual Studio to recognize that I'm using IBM DB2?

Comment: Looks like it may be from a proprietary dll, if so did you add it to the project's references?

Comment: Importing a namespace is meaningless if you haven't referenced an assembly that contains definitions of type that are members of that namespace. All the import does is allow you to use member types without qualifying them., It doesn't give you magic access to those member types. Learn about namespaces and assemblies and referencing assemblies. I would assume that the installed tools would allow you to create a typed DataSet and that would add the required reference(s) automatically but, apart from that, the same rules apply here as apply for any types in any libraries.

Comment: [This](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/12/referencing-assemblies-and-importing.html) may be a good place to start reading.

Comment: I'll 2nd the comments here. Did you first reference the .dll and assembly that you downloaded? You can't use imports until such time  you referenced those new libraries. On the other hand? If this is JUST a ODBC driver? Then you use the ODBC provider in .net as opposed to say oleDB, or the common sql provider (which is often referred to ado.net).  With just the ODBC driver, then you not really required to use any special IBM imports, but if your following their examples? Then yes, you need a reference to the downloaded .dll(s) before imports can be used.